# How do you control Azure SQL Serverless scaling?

Tags: azure-sql-database

I am using Azure SQL Serverless, but I find it is often "too large".

By that I mean that I am getting very low CPU utilization (~3%) but my billable vCore's indicate I'm using near 30-50% of my max vCore configuration.

Is there any way to configure Azure SQL so that it will not scale up the compute unless utilization is very high (90%+)?

Answer (score 1):

There's no custom configuration for the autoscale behavior.  But you can always turn off autoscale and use your own [Alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/alerts-insights-configure-portal) to trigger a Azure Automation Runbook or Azure Function to reconfigure the vCores.

Comment: Our data volume would make it very expensive to use provisioned compute. The alternative would be to go to the Hyperscale tier to allow for large data volumes with 2 vCores as the min configuration.

Comment: I was not suggesting changing to provisioned compute, but providing your own scaling logic for serverless.

Comment: Ah, that could work. Can you point me to the command to change the vCore allocation?